# wrong added values in baccarat game

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to code a basic Baccarat game, but when I try to add the value of the player's cards together, I'm getting random numbers. The code should take the values of all of its card integers, add them together, and take the one's digit of the number.

Here's my code to get and add the values of the numbers:

```java
public void TakeACard(String c) {
    char number;
    String temp;
    allCard = allCard+c+" ";

    if (c.charAt(0)=='J' || c.charAt(0)=='Q' || c.charAt(0)=='K') {
        value = 0;
    } else if (c.charAt(0)=='A') {
        value = 1;
    } else {
        number = c.charAt(0);
        value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    hand[numCards] = value;
    numCards++;
}

public void GetTotalValue(){

    for (int i = 0; i<numCards; i++){
        value = hand[i];
        total += value;
    }

    int finalValue = total%10;

    System.out.print("Your hand value is: "+ finalValue);
}
```

Here is the sample output that I am getting:

> Your cards are: 2, 6. Your hand value is: 8
>
> Click 1 to get your cards, and click anything else to stop choosing 1
>
> Your cards are: 2, 6, A. Your hand value is: 7
>
> Click 1 to get your cards, and click anything else to stop choosing 1
>
> Your cards are: 2, 6, A, 5. Your hand value is: 1

Does anyone have an idea on why they are not adding together properly and how I can fix it?

Comment: you dont set `total = 0;` in `GetTotalValue`, did you check whether it might have a different starting value?

Comment: I  just set total as 0 in the beginning of my class, but the same issue occurred.

Comment: @rether Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not resetting total. It's a class variable which will keep growing and growing. What's happening is entirely expected. Let's see:

2 + 6 = 8 (total) --> 8 % 10 = 8

8 (current total) + 2 + 6 + 1 = 17 --> 17 % 10 = 7

17 (current total) + 2 + 6 + 1 + 5 = 31 --> 31 % 10 = 1

Here is how you correct it:

```
public void GetTotalValue(){
    total = 0; // <---- ADD THIS RESET

    for (int i = 0; i<numCards; i++){
        value = hand[i];
        total += value;
    }

    int finalValue = total%10;

    System.out.print("Your hand value is: "+ finalValue);
}
```

And just a little thing, don't name your function `Get...` when it returns `void`. Either return something or rename the function to something else. It's harder to maintain your code when you do not follow any naming convention.